# How to stream 24/7 on youtube (audio + video) with FFMPEG

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I plan to create a 24/7 stream with a video and a musical background which is located in a `/Playlist` folder.
I would like the music playlist to be played randomly and if a piece of music is corrupted or cannot be played, the program moves on to the next one.

The problem is that with my command every time the music changes the stream stops.
Any suggestions ?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

VBR="4500k"
FPS="30"
QUAL="superfast"

YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
KEY="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"

VIDEO_SOURCE="fireplace.mkv"
AUDIO_FOLDER="/home/administrateur/Documents/Youtube/Playlist"

while true; do
    # Joue la vidéo en boucle
    ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i "$VIDEO_SOURCE" \
    -thread_queue_size 512 -i "$(find "$AUDIO_FOLDER" -type f -name "*.mp3" | shuf -n 1)" \
    -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 \
    -map_metadata:g 1:g \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale:v 3 -b:a 320000 -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
done
```

I would like the `fireplace.mkv` video to play without interruption, for the music to be chosen randomly without ever stopping. And if one of the songs cannot be played, it is skipped.

Comment: Not really my domain of knowledge, but I can see already: In each iteration of the loop, you create a new `ffmpeg` process, i.e. the old one has to terminate, an new one needs to be started and initialized. This can't work in zero time. Therefore, you need a way to feed a new video to ffmpeg while the current one is still playing. I don't know whether ffmpeg provides such a feature, but if it does, your question boils down to "how to use ffmpeg in such a way". In this case, your question is not about programming, and should be asked at, i.e. [video.se].